# How to open xlsx file from vuejs2 page?

Tags: vuejs2, vuejs-routing

In laravel/vuejs2 site  with "vue-router": "^3 I need to open xlsx file with command :

```
fileurl = ‘http://localhost/tmp/test-item.xlsx’;
window.open(fileurl,'_blank');
```

from javascript.

But not found event catcher is triggered in resources/js/routes.js :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
    routes,
    mode: 'history'
});


router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (!to.matched.length) {
        console.log('to.path::')
        console.log(to.path)

        alert( "::/not-found/" )
    } else {
        next();
    }
})
```

If to copypaste url in fileurl in browser I have the same not found event catcher.

If there is a way to open filename in this case(this filename can be different in different cases) in browser by OS reader or
some way to open xlsx file in some vuejs container ?

```
"vue": "^2.6.10"
"vue-router": "^3.0.7",
```

ATTEMPT TO SALVE :

I try to salve it in a different way and in file routes/web.php added line :

```
Route::get('/items/export-into-excel/{filename}', 'IndexController@exportIntoExcel')->name('exportIntoExcel');
```

and in IndexController.php file I added exportIntoExcel method, but it is not called when from javascript I call :

```
window.open('/items/export-into-excel/' + encodeURIComponent(res.data.excelFileUrl),'_blank');
```

But it does not work anyway, as action is run by vuejs router and laravel action is not called.
If there is a way to bypass it somehow? Like all urls starting from some ‘/items/’ are not rendered by vuejs routes ?

**ATTEMPT TO SALVE # 2:**
I found a hint to use skipAuth option, but adding in routes :

```
    {
        path: '/tmp/*',
        meta: { skipAuth: true }
    },
```

I do not have "Not Found" error anymore, but common layout of my site is opened with empty content.
Actually I did not find any method like at skipAuth official docs at : https://v3.router.vuejs.org/
Please point where it is described?
How else my issue can be salved ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the issue is in laravel, if `tmp` path is a folder where you want to serve files from then you need to serve the file and not pass the request back to the clientside router to handle

Comment: Please read ATTEMPT TO SALVE

Comment: Please read ATTEMPT TO SALVE # 2